# How to pass billing address or user details in paypal using jquery in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, paypal

I'm using Braintree payments for PayPal payment getaway integration but I'm not able to pass parameter at PayPal.

jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
braintree.setup(
        // Replace this with a client token from your server
        " <?php print session('braintree_token')?>",
        "dropin", {
            container: "payment-form",
        });
```

});

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(e){

var paypal_public_key = document.getElementById('paypal_public_key').value;
var acount_type = document.getElementById('paypal_environment').value;
if(acount_type=='Test'){
  var paypal_environment = 'sandbox'
}else if(acount_type=='Live'){
  var paypal_environment = 'production'
}

   paypal.Button.render({
       enableBillingAddress: false,
  env: paypal_environment, // sandbox | production
  style: {
          label: 'checkout',
          size:  'small',    // small | medium | large | responsive
          shape: 'pill',     // pill | rect
          color: 'gold'      // gold | blue | silver | black
      },

  // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
  // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create

  client: {
    sandbox:     paypal_public_key,
    production:  paypal_public_key
  },

  // Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
  commit: true,

  // payment() is called when the button is clicked
  payment: function(data, actions) {
    var payment_currency = document.getElementById('payment_currency').value;
    var total_price = '<?php echo number_format((float)$total_price+0, 2, '.', '');?>';
      var billing_address = false;

    // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
    return actions.payment.create({

      payment: {
        transactions: [
          {
            amount: {
                total: total_price,
                currency: payment_currency,
            },

          }
        ]
      }
    });
  },



  // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
  onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

    // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
    return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
         jQuery('#update_cart_form').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="nonce" value='+JSON.stringify(data)+'>');
      jQuery("#update_cart_form").submit();
    });
  }

}, '#paypal_button');
```

};

and when I clicked on the PayPal button it will redirect to sandbox.paypal.com which is correct but it will not hide billing address it is still enabled and I have passed false.
So, my question is how to pass a parameter to PayPal checkout using jquery because I need to pass some more information about customer. So how to achieve that.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

All PayPal transactions process with a billing address. This is required.

The enableBillingAddress parameter is to request that that information be returned. Very few seller accounts can process payments with it set to true, so you should ignore this.

If you goal is to set prefilled information, you will need to set it with other fields, and it may be ignored when the user signs in, since signed-in users will have their own information already stored.

Comment: thanks for the reply. And can I pass user details like first name, last name or email address ??

Comment: You are using an old checkout.js integration, so here is the archived documentation https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/integrate/#2-set-up-a-payment

Comment: How to pass email or displayName the parameter in jquery which I have mentioned in my question ??